# Best way for automated script to determine whether git is really installed on OS X

Tags: git, macos

I can locate executables named `git` in several ways (basically equivalent to `which git`). But all of the solutions I know about are defeated by OS X's fake `/usr/bin/git` program, which is a hook to a dialog offering to install Xcode's `git` (I'll refer to it subsequently as the *OS X git installer*.)

I want to detect that situation and treat `git` as not found if that is the only one. I don't want to have to execute it to determine that, because I don't want to trigger the installer dialog.

Context: I'd like to implement the following (as part of a larger software installation process):

- Determine whether a "real" git is installed (i.e., an executable named `git`, other than the OS X git installer, is on the `PATH`),
- If it is, recognize and respect it and proceed (I have this part figured out),
- If it is not, install the one from the git project (I have this part figured out).

I am comfortable parsing `PATH` if needed and searching for executables myself, if I can find a way to ignore the OS X git installer. I am comfortable with a heuristic if it gets this right almost all the time; I don't need to handle edge cases (like someone creating an executable or script called `git` that is not `git`-compatible).

What's the best (most robust, secondarily most convenient) way to determine whether a non-OS X git installer `git` is installed on a system *without* executing `/usr/bin/git` (and triggering the installer dialog)?

Comment: If the stub git is in the PATH and you use a command like `git --version`, can you parse the results to determine if the git is the stub or not?

Comment: ha, while you were writing that comment, I was writing a clarification as to why I can't do that in a (hopefully improved) question. So no, executing git --version pops up the installer dialog (unless there's some tricky way to avoid it, some trick for doing it headlessly or something).

Comment: One possibility would be to make a guess based on the size of the file. Another possibility would be to determine the difference based on the output of ``strings `which git` ``.

Comment: I had thought of the first idea, but not the second, which is excellent (thank you).

Comment: I can't test conveniently, but you could see what `xcode-select -p` and `xcrun -f git` show on a system that hasn't had Xcode or the Command Line Tools installed vs. one where those are installed.

Comment: `xcrun` pops up a dialog, but `xcode-select` I am investigating ...

Comment: @ThomasW `strings` also comes with the Xcode tools, alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I have my answer, of the heuristic variety.

IF:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/` does not exist,

AND:
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` does not exist,

THEN:
`/usr/bin/git` is the stub, and it can be ignored.

Obviously there are failure cases possible; people can move those files around, people can create executables named `git` that are not `git`-compatible, but this seems to be the 99% solution and turns out to be a little easier than I thought.

I haven't yet investigated what will happen if I install the git project's `git`, and what will happen in the `PATH` (will the Apple non-tool still be first?). If that changes anything substantial I'll report back; I am guessing if Apple's tool is still first in the `PATH`, I'll have my installation process move or delete it, or possibly change the `PATH` it uses, or something.

Comment: In El Capitan with System Integrity Protection enabled (the default), not even root can move or delete things in /usr/bin.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks -- I didn't know /usr/bin was one of *those*. :) I am still toying with the alternatives -- having my installed software attempt to change the PATH or just punting and using Apple's software (and prompting people to install that by simply running `/usr/bin/git`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way. There are some things that defy automated discovery and I can certainly have `$HOME/bin/git` which isn't `git` but is in my path.

What you can do is make the path to git as a configurable item with a reasonable default and document it well. The `git` program itself does this itself; it will look for configuration items in a [few different places](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) and finally allows `git --file configfile` as a last option to override.

Comment: I'm willing to rely on the idea that if someone has a `git` then it's really `git` (or some kind of compatible script or alias). The only exception I'm looking to handle is the Apple `/usr/bin/git` stock install, which is not really `git`, but a hook to a graphical Xcode installer dialog. I would like to detect that situation and treat `git` as not found in that case. I've edited the question to be clearer.